# git checkout with different node_modules folder

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have two branches, one called "gh-pages" and the other "master" branch. Both are having separate folders like "node_modules", but they are completely different. And they are untracked!

So when checking out e.g. the "gh-pages" branch as follows

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

I need a way to specify that Git should not just remove (but save) all tracked, but also all untracked files and folders (like the "node_modules" folder) from the "master" branch. And then load all tracked files and folders from the "gh-pages" branch and as well as all untracked files and folders.

Is there a simple way or do I really need to remove untracked files and folders for each checkout so that the two do not come into the cross?

Answer (score 5):

I suffered the problem too. And my workaround is using `git worktree`. Create linked working tree for each branch, put the node_modules in it instead of main working tree.

See this similar question: 
[Switch node_modules folder when I change git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905973/switch-node-modules-folder-when-i-change-git-branch)

This article explains why it is better than `git clone`: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/26/parallelize-development-git-worktrees/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in git. By definition untracked files are part of file system and not `git's` version control.

**git checkout**

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.

So when you checkout a branch you just get the working copy of files in that branch. Since untracked files like `node_modules` are not part of any specific branch but the local file system it will remain as it is.

Comment: Do you know any workaround? I mean having a gh-pages branch with different node modules is a common behavior on GitHub.

Comment: Make them part of your VCS and track them :)

Comment: you can not be serious right? In a current project there would be about 60MB node modules with over 14000 files, where the actual 66 source files are just 176 KB large...

Comment: The thing you are looking is not possible without tracking them in repo

Answer (score 0):

I also had to choose `git worktree` for this purpose. Below is how I was able to do it in step-by-step.

1. Create the `gh-pages` branch as an orphan branch.
   `git checkout --orphan gh-pahes`
2. Create a git worktree off the `gh-pages` branch.
   `git worktree add <worktree_name> gh-pages`
3. A new directory will have been created with the name `<worktree_name>` by now. `cd` to that folder and run `npm install`. Changing the directory to this folder equals checking out the `gh-pages` branch.
4. Now you can develop your Github Pages site and push it to `gh-pages` branch of the remote to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem as well as this can also be an issue when upgrading the dependencies listed in the `package.json` (another branch may still have the old `package.json` in which case modules in `node_modules` could be at the wrong versions after switching branches).

One of my ideas is to setup a local `git checkout` hook which runs `npm ci` every time I switch/checkout different branches or commits. This requires having/using and tracking/committing a `package-lock.json` however, plus (re)installing might take too long on bigger projects (in which case you may want to try something like `pnpm` in order to speed up installs).

Another idea is to simply use yarn v2 and then commit all of your dependencies/modules (which I believe yarn stores locally in what it calls its `cache`). Also, I could be wrong but I believe you can also run `npm ls` and it will error if `node_modules` does not match the project/package manifests (not sure if this is well-documented however, nor do I know much about the finer details of what it does and doesn't verify).