# Switch node_modules folder when I change git branch

Tags: node.js, git, branch, node-modules

I'm working with two branches, `master` and `feature-1`

In the master branch I'm using a lib `xyz@1.0`

In the branch  `feature-1` I've installed a new version from lib `xyz` version `2.0`

`feature-1` was not merged yet on `master` branch, because  it's not done. Then when I switch to `master` again I've to re-install the `lib@1.0`, and if I switch again to `feature-1` I've to re-install the `lib@2.0`

What's the best workflow approach in theses cases?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You do things well with git and each time you switch, you have to do your `npm i`.

But perhaps if you switch very often from one branch to the other, you should think about using **git worktree** introduced in some recent git versions and **which permit to have another branch checked out in another folder** (here `feature-1`) but sharing the same repository (perfect for this type of work flow!) .

That way you will be able to do the `npm i` once for each branch and work in parallel on each branch.

It's quite simple to use but I will let you have a look to the documentation.

Once you're finished, just delete the folder with the added workspace (but not the main one with the .git folder!)

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. I also have this kind of situations, work with different versions of the same project in different branches.